# Setting Ultragrid source to datatable - blank cells

Tags: c#, datatable, ultrawingrid

I am trying to populate an ultragrid using a datatable, the datatable has 5 columns in which the data will be inserted into the according row depending on a string value. The issue I am getting is difficult to explain, the best I can explain it is that when I am inserting data into a column, it creates a completely new row so you can only have one column populated per row. I appreciate this is not very well explained, so apologies in advance.

I would like the results to be as below:

**Expected output**

```
Column1        Column2       Column3       Column4       Column5
  123            123           123           123           123
  546            546           546           546           546
```

**Actual Output**

```
Column1        Column2       Column3       Column4       Column5
  123                
                 123
                               123
                                             123
                                                           123
```

**Code**

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column3");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column4");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column5");
        lblItemCount.Text = string.Format("Current items within Sprint: {0}", task.Count().ToString());

        foreach (Task t in task)
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();

            if (t.AssignedTo == "Person1")
            {
                row["Column1"] = t.Id.ToString();
            }
            if (t.AssignedTo == "Person2")
            {
                row["Column2"] = t.Id.ToString();
            }
            if (t.AssignedTo == "Person3")
            {
                row["Column3"] = t.Id.ToString();
            }
            if (t.AssignedTo == "Person4")
            {
                row["Column4"] = t.Id.ToString();
            }
            if (t.AssignedTo == "Person5")
            {
                row["Column5"] = t.Id.ToString();
            }

                dt.Rows.Add(row);

        }
        grdTFSItems.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: I guess you want to group the tasks by the person assigned. Is that correct?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes pretty much, it's grouped to the person assigned but I want rows with numerous columns populated if you understand? At the moment, it is inserting a new row for each task.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to group by Id?

```
var idGroups = task
    .Where(t => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.AssignedTo))
    .GroupBy(t => t.Id);
foreach (var idGroup in idGroups)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    foreach (Task t in idGroup)
    {
        if (t.AssignedTo == "Person1")
            row.SetField("Column1", t.Id.ToString());
        else if(t.AssignedTo == "Person2")
            row.SetField("Column2", t.Id.ToString());
        else if (t.AssignedTo == "Person3")
            row.SetField("Column3", t.Id.ToString());
        else if (t.AssignedTo == "Person4")
            row.SetField("Column4", t.Id.ToString());
        else if (t.AssignedTo == "Person5")
            row.SetField("Column5", t.Id.ToString());
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Not sure this is the correct solution, it still looks like the same output as before but now has blank rows.

Comment: @JayH: it's because of your poor sample data. All of your columns contain the same ID which seems to be pointless. Also, your expected output contains ID'sd which are not  in the actual output. I assume you have simply omitted taks with ID=546 but that's just confusing. Try to show better samples. Your model is also confusing, why have you one column for every person? What happens if sometime there is a `Person6`?

Comment: There will never be a Person6, we only want to bring out data for the 5 people.

Comment: @JayH: note that i have edited my answer to avoid empty rows by selecting only rows which contain an `AssignedTo`. Acc. to the sample data my last comment still holds true.